# Express res.render is not rendering the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to get an input from my main site. After the input is submitted the page should redirect to `/view`. It seems like it successfully redirects to `/view` (because `console.log()` is getting triggered, but `res.render` is not working. If i manually go to `/view` it is rendering the page.

Here is the code of my `app.js` file:

```
// load the things we need
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let article = '';



//Set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/static', express.static('static'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())



//Index page 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index')
});

//Get the input from the form
app.post('/searcharticle', function (req, res) {
    article = req.body.article;
    res.redirect('/view')
    return article;
});
//Page to output the input
app.get('/view', function (req, res) {
    console.log(article)
    res.render('view', {
        article: article
    })
})

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server on 8080');
```

And here is my 
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwlke.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: no there are no errors output @mehta-rohan

Comment: need to see your folder structure

Comment: I added the folder structure to the question @mehta-rohan

Comment: Unrelated: you have a race condition in your code because you store `article` globally. Request specific data does not belong in the global scope. You can for example store `req.body.article` it in the session, file system or a database. Or just `res.render` directly in your POST handler (there is also no need to return anything from it as the return value is discarded)

Answer (score 4):

use view engine first then set the directory where to use it.

```
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

and for static files use

```
app.use('/static',express.static(PATH.join(__dirname+'/static'));
```

Comment: I just get that error for the `app.use` of the static files: TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string
Does it really need that app.use for the static files like that? I haven't had a problem with the css files.

Comment: Sorry my bad i forgot to use express static

Answer (score 0):

supposed you have al your .ejs files in views folder try adding this line in your code:

```
const path = require('path'); //npm install -S path in your console to install path. 

//Set the view engine to ejs
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));  // add this one, change 'views' for your folder name if needed.
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/static', express.static('static'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: I added the lines but it is still not working. I get the same results.

Comment: could you share your folder structure?

Comment: issue may be in app.set('views',..)

Comment: I added a link to the structure on the bottom of the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your server from a diff directory than static you need to add a relative path

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname+'/static'))

Comment: But the css is working so there should not be a problem with the static files i guess

Answer (score 0):

I was just given the solution to a very similar problem by my wonderful tutor.  The login form 'submit' was passed to jQuery on('click') and after authetication called a Res.Render of the results of an API call.  The API call result set was log-abled, but the page never rendered, and there was no error.
He told me that jQuery acts as a 'shadow' DOM, and that the Res.Render was likewise taking place in that shadow DOM.  I changed the login form to a form Post  instead of the jQuery on Click.
That WORKED! 
I worked on this for several days without ever thinking jQuery could cause that obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to mention the layout**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index',{layout:false})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My way is to go back the version of ejs to 2.5.2, and that works. However, I don't know the reason why it cannot support the version 3.*.*