# res.render not working with fetch api on button to push ejs,how to fix and why is it not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, ejs, partials

I looked up my problem and found this [Express res.render is not rendering the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091903/express-res-render-is-not-rendering-the-page) none of the answers helped and none of the others on google worked. I am trying to push a post request with a button that renders a partial ejs file to the screen. It will later get deleted and replaced when i add another button but that is a task for next time. No error is given. The client console.log works and the server console.log works.

here is my server js

```
const { request } = require('express')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb'}))


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('layout')
})

app.post('/',async(req,res)=>{
     try {
    res.render('./partials/hi')
   } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
   }
})



app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log('server listening')
})
```

here is my main js (vanilla js)

```
const button = document.getElementById('button')
```

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
// const hi = document.createElement(`<%-require('../views/partials/hi.ejs')%>`)

```
// document.appendChild(hi)
console.log('no')

const options = {
    method : 'POST',
}

fetch('/', options)
```

})

here is the zip file (safe)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vwu7VDv613hRKFCZQhBNbONaT4Dk_0x1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it isnt possible guys

backend should only send data and dosent send pages that well why is ejs a thing i dont know but i wasnt going to work how i wanted to use it the answer is to build api and html separte and learn fetch and use it to call api and loop through api data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).